# A mixed problem !!!

Tags: number-theory

Let $p=2021$ be a prime number. Let E be the expected value of the expression$$ 3□3□3□⋯□3□3$$ where there are $p+3$ threes and $p+2$ boxes, and one of the four arithmetic operations {${+,−,×,÷}$} is uniformly chosen at random to replace each of the boxes. If $E=\frac{m}{n}$ , where m and n are relatively prime positive integers, find the remainder when m+n is divided by p.

`My Approach:`
I used python to answer the question as I am not getting the question. My code,

from random import choice

from fractions import Fraction as f

a = ['+','-','*','/']

b = 3

for i in range(1,2024):

```
 c = choice(a)
 if c == '+':
     b += 3
 elif c == '-':
     b -= 3
 elif c == '*':
     b *= 3
 else:
     b /= 3
```

The code gives different answers, but none is the correct, can anyone give me hint to solve the problem??

Comment: What is the relation between the choosing of the arithmetic operations and the values of m and n? It seems they are independents.

Comment: This seems likely to come down to ambiguities in expressions of the form $3\div 3\times 3$ and the like. b But what do you mean the code yields "different answers"?

Comment: Your first supposal is not correct: Let $p=2021$ be a prime number.

Comment: That $p$ is prime (or not) is anyway utterly irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: If we have each choice for every box, the problem is incredibly complicated. If we have the choice only once, how do we interprete the expression if every box has a ":" ? I guess we just divide repeatedly by $3$. In this case, we just have to consider the $4$ possible results.

Comment: Your code considers all operators as the same level of precedence, so for example $3+3\times 3 + 3 := (((3+3)\times 3)+3$. Which may not be what the question expects.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Condition on the last box that is not $\times $ or $ \div$.

There is an equal chance that it is $ + $ or $ - $.
Condition on sequences suitably to show that the expected value of the tail-end terms cancels out.

Keep on going.
Show that we just need to consider the first block of terms which only use $ \times $ or $ \div$, then weight by the probability of the length.
If there were $n$ boxes originally, then what is the probability that the first block of terms which only use $\times$ or $\div$ has $k$ boxes?

If there are $k$ boxes with only $ \times $ or $\div $ involved, then what is the expected value? (Use your favorite order of operations interpretation, which I hope is left to right for only $\times$ and $\div$ involved.)

Hence, what is the expected value for $n+1$ boxes?